# Swift 3 script does not run PHP script to insert data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, swift, swift3

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to make a simple app to put names in a MySQL database. When I run the Swift script in simulator, nothing changes in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Connect.php

```
//Connect to Database
$user="something_net_something";
$host="something.net.mysql";
$password="SecretPassword";
$database="something_net_something";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("connection to server failed");
mysqli_select_db($connection,$database) or die ("couldn’t select database");
```

Function.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
//Connect to Database
include "Connect.php";
//getting values
$fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$lname = $_POST['Lname'];
//query
$QRY="INSERT INTO oneiros_aether_personage (Fname, Lname) VALUES ($fname, $lname)";
if (mysqli_query($connection, $QRY)) {
    $response['error']=false;
    $response['message']="New record created successfully";
} else {
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']="Error: " . $QRY . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($connection);
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//URL to our web service
let URL_ADD_PERSONAGE = "http://www.something.net/Function.php"


//TextFields declarations
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldFname: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldLname: UITextField!


//Button action method
@IBAction func buttonSave(sender: UIButton) {

    //created NSURL
    let requestURL = URL(string: URL_ADD_PERSONAGE)

    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    //getting values from text fields
    let fname = textFieldFname.text
    let lname = textFieldLname.text

    //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
    let postParameters = "Fname="+fname!+"&Lname="+lname!;

    //adding the parameters to request body
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }

        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                //creating a string
                var msg : String!

                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                //printing the response
                print(msg)

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

To Info.plist I added

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Have you tried narrowing down the problem? What have you tried? Is there a problem with the SQL setup, php script, your app?

Comment: @milo526 in the Function.php I changed the $_POST[ ] with fixed strings and script added the strings to my database, so I assume somethings wrong in the swift code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code works fine with me,
check the `URL_ADD_PERSONAGE` variable, `IBOutlet` and others.

**The connection logic has no error.**

Comment: Thanks @wajeeh , I figgered it out, it was the IBAction. Removed it and I dragged it again from the Main to ViewController. Now it works fine.